# Creating advanced KnockOut binding handler for google.visualization.datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, google-visualization

Thanks to this [tutorial](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/Articles/2014/04/01/Using-Knockout-Custom-Binding-Handlers.aspx)  I managed to create a KnockOut binding handler for Google's DataTable.
This is my binding handler, so far:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.dataTable = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var table = new google.visualization.Table(element);
        ko.utils.domData.set(element, "dataTable", table);
    },

    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());

        // Get options:
        var options = allBindings.get("tableOptions") || {};
        // Default options:
        options.width = options.width || "200px";
        options.height = options.height || "200px";
        options.showRowNumber = options.showRowNumber || false;

        // Get events:
        var onSelected = allBindings.get("select") || false;
        if (onSelected) {
            $(element).on("select", function(event, ui) {
                valueAccessor()(ui.value);
            });
        }

        var table = ko.utils.domData.get(element, "dataTable");
        table.draw(value, options);
    }
};
```

This is my HTML part:

```
<div data-bind="dataTable: $root.getData(), tableOptions: {width: '100%',height: '200px', 'allowHtml': true, 'cssClassNames': {'selectedTableRow': 'orange-background'} }"></div>
```

So far I get a table with fixed headers which works just fine.
Now I want to extent to binding handler to react on the 'select row' event.
I tried this using the `// Get events` section in my handler but this is not working.

In my HTML I add `select: $root.selectedRow(),`
In my function `selectedRow()` I put a `console.log("In selectedRow")`. When I load the page I see `selectedRow` is called for every row, but when I click on a row it is not called.

The row its background is changed to orange, so Google is adding the `selectedTableRow` class.

How to wrap/bind to the select event?

Comment: Have you tried adding the event listener using `google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'select', selectHandler);` ?

Comment: Do you mean 'outside' KnockOut? On my page I have multiple tables. My tables are quit narrow. When I click on a row I want to display the full row data in a div below the table. So I need to know which table I'm in and which row I selected. To fill the div I'm using a observable, I just need to know how to fill that observable.

Comment: I meant in your binding handler, instead of the `$(element).on("select", ...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main thing that's going wrong is, if I'm not mistaken, the way you're trying to attach your event listener.

Your `$(element).on("select", onSelect)` is not how the library you're using attaches event listeners. In the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#addlistener) you can see that you actually need to use: `google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'select', selectHandler);`

Additionally, it's better to attach the event listener in the `init` method. `update` is called whenever your data changes, so it might add multiple event listeners.

Here's a working example of your code:

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['table']
});

google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function() {

  ko.bindingHandlers.dataTable = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
      var table = new google.visualization.Table(element);
      ko.utils.domData.set(element, "dataTable", table);

      // Get events:
      var onSelected = allBindings.get("select") || false;
      if (onSelected) {
        google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'select', function() {
          // TODO: null/undefined/multiple selection checks
          var data = valueAccessor();
          var row = table.getSelection()[0].row;
          onSelected(data.getValue(row, 1)); // Sends salary of clicked row
        });
      }

    },

    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
      var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());

      // Get options:
      var options = allBindings.get("tableOptions") || {};
      // Default options:
      options.width = options.width || "200px";
      options.height = options.height || "200px";
      options.showRowNumber = options.showRowNumber || false;


      var table = ko.utils.domData.get(element, "dataTable");
      table.draw(value, options);
    }
  };

  ko.applyBindings({
    onSelect: function(value) {
      alert(value);
    },
    getData: function() {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Salary');
      data.addColumn('boolean', 'Full Time Employee');
      data.addRows([
        ['Mike', {
            v: 10000,
            f: '$10,000'
          },
          true
        ],
        ['Jim', {
            v: 8000,
            f: '$8,000'
          },
          false
        ],
        ['Alice', {
            v: 12500,
            f: '$12,500'
          },
          true
        ],
        ['Bob', {
            v: 7000,
            f: '$7,000'
          },
          true
        ]
      ]);
      return data;

    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div data-bind="dataTable: getData(), tableOptions: {width: '100%',height: '200px', 'allowHtml': true, 'cssClassNames': {'selectedTableRow': 'orange-background'} }, select: onSelect"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this very explaining answer. I have one more question: How to get the value of the selected row? I assumed I could use 
`onSelect: function(row) {
       alert("Selection " + row);
     }`
 but row is empty. getSelection() needs a table and I have multiple tables.

Comment: You could wrap your `onSelected` in an anonymous method. In this method, `table` refers to the "current" table, and you can pass it to the selection method. e.g.: `google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'select', function() { onSelected(table.getSelection()); });`

Comment: I'm sorry to keep asking, but it seems you know a lot about this ;) `table.getSelection()` returns an array with the selected row and column indexes not the actual value. I tried passing `table` into my onSelected: `google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'select', function() { onSelected(table); });` and use `var item = table.getSelection()[0]; console.log(table.getValue(item.row, 3));` But `getValue` is not available for the table object. I think I should call it on the actual data but I don't have this variable as a global.

Comment: `getValue` is a function in your `DataTable`, which is accessible through `valueAccessor()` inside the `init` and `update` methods of your binding. Which means you'll also be able to access it in the anonymous function we've created.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. It is working great. I'll accept your answer. Now I'm going to update it to use RequireJS (first attempt failed :))